# Reflected object access using a string

Tags: c#, regex, reflection

I'd like to access to a generic object using only a string. I know that with reflection it is possible to access to generic object, so I need to parse correctly the string expression, extract object accesses tokens, and execute them using reflection.

It seems quite easy, but I found difficoulties in the expression parsing because regular expression.

My final target should be a string rendering, based on object properties. An example is the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx), which allow to produce a string by accessing to an object.
I didn't find anything useful for performing the string processing; so I've started to manually parse the expression string using regular expression.

For example, the following expression it quite easy:

```
"MyFixedString = {PropertyName}"
```

So, the tokens enclosed to "{ ... }" represents an object property. Extract the property name, get the value using reflection, calls the *ToString()* method and replace it on the expression string to get the result.

But Id like to perform more complex object access:

```
"MyFixedString = {Property.Method(\"MyMethodArg.1\", \"MyMethodArg.2\").Field}"
```

Of course, I understand that object accesses are separated by dots (but this is not simple since the dots could be present in another elements (i.e. method arguments). Additionally, I need to recognize methods, field/properties, indexed properties.

Sadly, I'm missing regular expression basics (i swear i'll study them!).

So, my question is: is there some built-in class which do what I need? If not, I need a regular expression which split the input string by a single character (in my cases are dots and commas), but don't split in the case the character is enclosed in double quotes.

The last example would be splitted in

- Property
- Method(\"MyMethodArg.1\", \"MyMethodArg.2\")

  - Method
  - "MyMethodArg.1\"
  - \"MyMethodArg.2\"
- Field

Comment: Regexes are fraught. A regex that splits parameters on commas will get awfully confused if one of the parameters is `\"Hello, world!\"`.

Comment: Infact I asked for a regex which split strings by a single character which is not enclosed by single/double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at [FormatWith](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables.aspx).